# Mounted Drives To Show In Devices

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, devices

When I have an extra drive plugged into the computer, it shows in "devices" as shown here with the 250G filesystems:

[image]

However, once added to /etc/fstab` for automatic mounting, it will no longer appears as a device and it is up to the user to know where all the drives are mounted if they do not want to use the root partition.

Example fstab line:

```
UUID=9ea922e4-94ce-4ae0-90cf-65a4957051bd       /mnt/extra_storage      ext4    defaults        0       2
```

**Is there a way to register a drive as a device such that tools like duplicity will automatically show them in their menus etc?** Perhaps I just need to mount somewhere other than `/mnt`?

[image: Duplicity helpfully shows additional drives for storage]
**Image Description:** Duplicity lists drives as places to store, but I have make sure to use "local folder" which makes it appear as if I am storing the backup on the drive I am backing up.

Comment: Why are you using fstab at all? Why not just let them be mounted automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default only devices mounted in "/media"  will be shown in the sidebar. And whan there is no fstab entry those devices will be mounted in "/media".

So change

```
/mnt/extra_storage
```

to

```
/media/extra_storage
```

and Nautilus will pick it up.

There is also a dconf setting that can be set to prevent mounting:

[image]

Comment: It now shows the drive's label (not the folder mounted to in /media) in the devices menu thanks :)